# Reading String in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, string

```
String strFCKeditor1 = request.getParameter("FCKeditor1");
```

i want to read this (strFCKeditor1)string and want to replace `"` with `\"` in it.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
strFCKeditor1 = strFCKeditor1.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

This is the "Java-string-escaped" way of saying *replace `"` with `\"`*

See [ideone.com demo here](http://ideone.com/3CHgL).

From the documentation of `replace`:

> *Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.*